# How do I count Yes / NO drop-down answers from another workbook?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a drop down with a "Yes" or "No" option in column H of my source Google Sheet workbook, on a tab called "Answers 2023"

I'm trying to count the number of times "Yes" is selected from that drop down in column H,and pull that number in to a master workbook. The column will have more added to it over time, so I was trying to create the formula to look at the entire column, not just a range of the rows that are already populated.

So far, I've been trying to use this formula, with no luck:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(“url”;”Answers 2023!H:H");"select H Count(H) where H ="Yes"")
```

I've also tried replacing H with Col8:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(“url”;”Answers 2023!H:H");"select Col8 Count(Col8) where Col8 ="Yes"")
```

Even using "," in place of ";"

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(“url”, ”Answers 2023!H:H"), "select Col8 Count(Col8) where Col8 ="Yes"")
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Hey guys. Thanks for your help and feedback. Unfortunately, I get the below error:
#VALUE!

Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: LABEL_COL_NOT_IN_SELECT: COUNT(`Col8`)


I decided to try: 
 =COUNTIF(IMPORTRANGE("url", "Answers 2023!H:H"), “Yes”)
Which gives me at Formula parse error

Finally, I tried the formula below, which works a little. It's counting every cell in column H that has a value in it...no matter what, which is so odd.:
=INDEX(COUNTA(IFNA(QUERY(IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE("url", "Answers 2025!H:H"), "Count Col8 where Col8='Yes’”,0")))))

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("url"; "Answers 2023!H:H");
      "select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 ='yes' 
       group by Col1 label count(Col1) '' ")
```

*(**Do** adjust the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

Make sure you use correctly your single and double quotes.

Comment: This should work. +1 from me.

Answer (score -1):

This solved my original inquiry

```
=COUNTIF(IMPORTRANGE("url", "Answers 2023!H:H"), "No")
```